# Compiling/Building R from source for Windows 10 - Does not detect bzlib.h

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I am running 64 bit windows 10 and I wish to build R (64 bit) from source.

When building the core files from cmd by executing

```
make all recommended vignettes
```

from my R_HOME/R-3.3.1/src/gnuwin32 directory, the code compiles for some time but finally fails with the following error:

```
In file included from dounzip.x:30.0:
unzip.h:83:19: fatal error: bzlib.h: No such file or directory
# include "bzlib.h"
```

My PATH variable has the following as its first 4 locations (c:\Rtools\bin; R\tools\mingw_64\x64\; c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\; x:\R64\R3.3.1\bin)

I have also explicitly defined the user TMP variable to C:/temp

There is a copy of bzlib.h in the folder c:\Rtools\mingw_64\opt\include (which I note is not explicitly in, or below the PATH, but I don't know if thats a problem.)

I have tried this with the combination of (Rtools34 + R source R-3.3.1), as well as (Rtools33 + R-3.3.0).

When installing Rtools I included the following:
R toolset, CygwinDLLs, R33.x+ 64 bit toolchain, Extras to build 64bit R: TCL/TK.  (Note that I did not install any 32 bit files).

Prior to compiling the core code I installed all external binary distributions of third-party software by executing the command

```
make rsync-extsoft
```

which gave me all the recommended third party binary packages.

I also downloaded and unpacked ICU and qpdf and linked their location in gnuwin32/Makefile.local

I have also updated the BLAS (extra/blas/Makefile.win) to point to my locally compiled openBLAS package (the reason I am building R from source), and have updated the appropriate ATLAS variables in Makefile.local

I'm not sure what I've missed. I have tried installing the package bzip2-1.0.6 from zip and tar, but I don't know where to put the unpacked contents for it to be useful.

Comment: I am stuck with this too...I even have `bzlib.h` in `C:\R64\extsoft\include`

Comment: Hi! I did end up resolving this issue, although I can't seem to remember right now how I did it exactly.  I recall I opened up the script that the system was running when it failed (the line above the error message will tell you what it was) and read it to find where it failed for bzlib.h.  I believe the script has the path it is looking in and I moved the files there.  
My bzlib.h file came with the external software which I automatically downloaded. However the script placed them in the level above my main R directory. At the moment I have the folder extsoft directly under R-3.3.1.

Comment: thanks. adding  `-I../../extsoft/include` to line 9 (`CPPFLAGS`) of `src\main\Makefile.win` seems to solve the problem...but now I get another error...i'll post an answer if that really solves it

Comment: The other error I got (`platform.c: In function 'Init_R_Platform': platform.c:177:5: error: stray '\' in program`) turned out to be indeed unrelated and solvable but putting `c:\Rtools\bin; R\tools\mingw_64\x64\;` at the beginning of the system path (instead of user path)

Comment: @Rosie you should post this as an answer. As @YAK says, running `make rsync-extsoft` then editing CPPFLAGS fixes the problem.